# twitteR - Constructing a graph of users based on their location

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using the twitteR library. My task is to make a graph where vertices are the usernames and if two users are from the same location, there will be an edge between them.
This is the code I used to collect the users

```
search_result <- searchTwitter("#my_hashtag", 500)
tags <- twListToDF(search_result)
users <- tags$screenName
df <- twListToDF(lookupUsers(users))
```

I'm new to R, so I assume this task is very simple but I lack the syntax to generate the pairs of users, which will represent the edges of the graph.

Your help will be appreciated! :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a while thinking, I think this is the simplest approach. **I follow your example from the last point**. The next step is to stay only with the user's name and location. We will use 'dplyr' to create the necessary edgelist matrix, set `loops` to `FALSE` to avoid loops in graph and I also set `directed = FALSE`, the opposite doesn't make sense. Once we have done it any of the packages availables can be used to create the graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library("statnet")
p <- df[,c("name", "location")]

inner_join(p,p, by="location") %>% 
  select(name.x, name.y) -> gr

n <- network(gr, matrix.type="edgelist", loops = F, directed = F)
gplot(n,usearrows = F)
```

I have only used a couple of users, in addition to mine, to make the network simple. Two are connected and another is not:

[image]

HTH!